# GPS Android find location application

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locate

Is it possible to create a GPS application using Google Maps to locate the position of items. To do this, I think that the process would be to attatch a GPS transmiting device to an item (such as car keys or sun glasses) and if you lose them, their position can be located.

I have developed some Android Cell Phone applications and would want to make the application to locate the devices for the cell phone market.

For this situation, what would be the best transmitting device to get?

Answer (score 0):

When I misplace my sunglasses, keys, or something they usually end up somewhere out of a line of sight to the satellites ... Thus, even if these items had a GPS receiver they would not be able to get a fix. 
Additionally those items need to be able to communicate their location to your device or the internet. And those items need a power source to operate the GPS (and the communication device).

In my opinion, for indoor lost item it would be better to use some signal form the items and then home in on the signal (bluetooth, wifi, whatever). This also needs less power than GPS.